# Upgrading topology from Python 2 to 3

Tags: streamparse

I had a `Streamparse` topology that was originally developed using `Python 2`. I am now trying to upgrade it to `Python 3` using the `2to3` tool. I have also upgraded `Streamparse` to `3.15.1` (not sure which version the topology was originally developed against). When I try to run my topology using `sparse run -d` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ShellBoltSpec' object has no attribute 'componentId'
```

I presume it is because the `ShellBoltSpec` class has changed from `Python 2` to `Python 3` but I have no idea how to go about fixing this. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of 2to3, it could be that upgrading Streamparse to version 3.x.x broke backwards compatibility with the previous version you worked with, if that was 2.x.x or below. If so, you need to explicitly edit your code to be compatible with Steamparse 3.x.x.